# How can two dependent variables have zero covariance?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, covariance

The following text is from [page 59 of chapter 3](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html) of the book Deep Learning by Ian Goodfellow et al.:

> Independence is a stronger requirement than zero covariance, because independence also excludes nonlinear relationships. It is possible for two variables to be dependent but have zero covariance.

> For example, suppose we ﬁrst sample a real number $x$ from a uniform distribution over the interval [−1,1]. We next sample a random variable $s$. With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we choose the value of $s$ to be 1. Otherwise, we choose the value of $s$ to be −1. We can then generate a random variable $y$ by assigning $y=sx$. Clearly, $x$ and $y$ are not independent, because $x$ completely determines the magnitude of $y$. However, $Cov(x, y) = 0$.

***What is the difference between sampling a real number and sampling a random variable?***
***How can I mathematically show that $Cov(x,y)=0$?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the same thing. It's just talking about sampling a number from the uniform distribution, call it X, on [-1,1], i.e. from $X\sim Unif[-1,1]$.

To calculate the covariance, you might note the formula $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. It is known that E(X)=0, beacause X is uniform on [-1,1], so pick the middle value. $E(Y)=E(SX)=E(S)E(X)$ (beacuse they are independent), and their individual expectations are 0, so E(Y)=0. We need to find E(XY) now. Note that $E(XY)=E(SX^2)=E(S)E(X^2)$ again because S and X are independent. So we get $0\cdot E(X^2)=0$. Thus $Cov(X,Y)=0$.

To show that X and Y are dependent events, note that the value of Y is half-determined by the value of X. So Y "depends" on X. To show mathematically that they are dependent, you must find sets A and B such that $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$ are events, where $P(Y\in B|X\in A)\ne P(Y\in B)$. Choose $A=[.25,.75],B=[.25,.75]$. Then $P(Y\in B)=\frac 1 4$ (this is because Y is also uniformly distributed on [-1,1]). But $P(Y\in B|X\in A)=\frac 1 2$. This is because given that $X\in[.25,.75]$, there is equal chance that $Y\in[.25,.75]$ or $Y\in[-.75,-.25]$. Thus we have found an events such that $P(Y\in B|X\in A)\ne P(Y\in B)$, and the random variables are dependent.

Two variables are independent if $P(X\in A\cap Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ for all possible combinations of sets A, B such that $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$. Equivalently, that $P(X\in A|Y\in B)=P(X\in A)$ for all possible combinations of events. This is obtained by dividing the first equation by $P(Y\in B)$.

Comment: Otherwise, we choose the value of s to be −1. So $P(s=1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and otherwise can be mathematically written as $P(s=-1) = \frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: Yes. It's implied that P(s=-1)=1/2

Comment: Just a question: what if $P(s=1)=\frac{1}{4}$ keeping everything else same? 
what would have happened as $x$ and $y$ would still be dependent? there would be $\frac{1}{4}$ probability for $y \in [025, 0.75]$ and $y$ would no longer be uniformly distributed on $[-1, 1]$? what would be $P(y)$?

Comment: If $s=\begin{cases}1&\frac 1 4\\-1&\frac 3 4\end{cases}$, $Y=\begin{cases}X &\frac 1 4 \\-X & \frac 3 4\end{cases}$, but $X=-X$. Thus $Y=X$ no matter the probabilities assigned to s's 1 and -1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your explanation? just that i am fairly new at this and could also give me some book name or some other reference which i can use to improve upon my understanding?

Comment: $Y=SX$, right? You have 3 random variables. And you can treat them as variables. X=-X because the uniform distribution is symmetric. Y=X means Y is distributed as X. It doesn't mean that Y=X's value. That is, y is uniform on [-1,1]. If you assume P(s=1)=1/4, keeping everything else the same, then $P(Y\in[.25,.75])=\frac 1 4$ because it's uniform (with no knowledge of X). But $P(Y\in [.25,.75)|X\in[.25,.75])=\frac 1 4$ now. Because s is 1/4 positive one, and -3/4 negative one. So Y is 1/4 in [.25,.75] and 3/4 in [-.75,-.25].

Comment: In this case, $\frac 1 4=\frac 1 4$, so this interval didn't show dependence. Notice that this doesn't show that they're independent. To show X and Y are independent, they need to be independent on all such intervals, a much larger task. Pick the interval A=[.25,.75] for Y and B=[.1,.2] for X. Then $P(Y\in A)=\frac 1 4$ but $P(Y\in A|X\in B)=0$. So they're dependent random variables. Note: In above comment I said X=-X because uniform distribution is symmetric, it should be symmetric *around X=0*.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

Covariance is a measure of the *linear* dependence of two random variables. $Cov(x,y)>0$ means something like the following: if I observe a relatively large $x$, I should also expect to observe a relatively large $y$. However, in the example you gave, if you observe a large $x$, you are equally likely to observe a large $y$ (if $s=1$) as you are to observe a small $y$ (if $s=-1$)! Hence $Cov(x,y)=0$, even though $y$ clearly depends on $x$.

To show $Cov(x,y)=0$ in your problem:

\begin{align}
Cov(x,y) &= Cov(x,sx)\\
&= \mathbb E[x^2 s] - \mathbb E[x]\mathbb E[s x] \\
&= \mathbb E[x^2] \mathbb [s]\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Where we used $\mathbb E[x]=\mathbb E[s]=0$, and the independence of $x$ and $s$, which implies $\mathbb E[x^2 s] = \mathbb E[x^2] \mathbb E[s]$.

In general, independent random variables necessarily have zero covariance, but random variables with zero covariance need not be independent as they may have higher moments which are nonzero.